# How can i compare two objects with different datatypes

Tags: javascript, json, object

How can I compare two object with different data types

```
var a = {
sort: 7,
start: "0"}

var b = {
sort: "7",
start: "0"}
```

I am expecting that both are equal. But its giving false when I use this comparison: `JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)`

Comment: it's `false` because `a.sort` is an `int` and `b.sort` is a `string`, they're not the same

Comment: I'd prefer changing the objects so they all contain either strings or numbers for the same property before comparing them, instead of considering them to be equal. You'll have to loop over all the entries and compare the `.toString()` values ( or use automatic casting by using == over === )  if you really want to do this, but it's bugs waiting to happen once your objects become more complex and you'll have to account for all special cases like `NaN` and `null` and all other values that don't stringify well.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to stingify the objects, then parse them [using a reviver](https://javascript.info/json#using-reviver) function to cast the strings to numbers, then stringify them back and compare :

```js
var a = {
  sort: 7,
  start: "0",
  x: "a"
}

var b = {
  sort: "7",
  start: "0",
  x: "a"
}

const strA = JSON.stringify(a);
const strB = JSON.stringify(b);

const x = JSON.parse(strA, (k, v) => {  
  return k && !isNaN(+v) ? +v : v;
})

const y = JSON.parse(strB, (k, v) => {
  return k && !isNaN(+v) ? +v : v;
})

const equal = JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y);

console.log(equal);
```